# how to insert values from an array into a table in oracle using delimiter

Tags: oracle, plsql

we are using a function like this

```
FUNCTION GetValue(i_string IN VARCHAR2
                 ,I_DELIM    IN VARCHAR2
                 ,i_occur    IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
i NUMBER;
j NUMBER;
BEGIN
i := INSTR(i_string, i_delim, 1, i_occur);
IF i = 0 THEN
  RETURN null;
ELSE
  IF i_occur > 1 THEN
    j := INSTR(i_string, i_delim, 1, i_occur-1);
    RETURN SUBSTR(i_string, j+1, i-j-1);
  ELSE
    RETURN SUBSTR(i_string, 1, i-1);
  END IF;
END IF;
```

user_id is the column that is to be inserted. In this case the values will be passed in an array like

```
00001,0
00002,1...
```

I want them to be inserted as

```
00001
00002..
```

What I've tried is

```
for i in 1 .. I_USER_ID.last
loop
V_USER_ID:= GETVALUE(I_USER_ID(i), ',', i);

 PROCEDURE310   (I_USER_ID    

                  ,C_PACKAGE_ID          
                  ,C_METHOD_ID          
                );
```

and I've taken T_user_id as the datatype.

This is not working.
please someone help.The value of 'i' is not being incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dummy data in an anonymous block you can see that only the first value pair in your list gets anything back from the function:

```
declare
  type T_USER_ID is table of varchar2(10) index by pls_integer;
  I_USER_ID T_USER_ID;
  V_USER_ID varchar2(10);
BEGIN

  I_USER_ID(1) := '00001,0';
  I_USER_ID(2) := '00002,1';
  I_USER_ID(3) := '00003,2';

  for i in 1 .. I_USER_ID.last
  loop
    V_USER_ID:= GETVALUE(I_USER_ID(i), ',', i);
    dbms_output.put_line(V_USER_ID);
  end loop;
END;
/

00001
(null)
(null)
```

For each pair of values you're asking for the "i-th" element in that shorter comma-separated. So for the first pair you're asking for the first element, for the second you're asking for the second, etc., which isn't what you need - you always want the first element from every pair. SO you always need to pass `1` as the third argument to your function:

```
    V_USER_ID:= GETVALUE(I_USER_ID(i), ',', 1);
```

Which now gets:

```
00001
00002
00003
```

---

Incidentally, your function can never return the last element from a list. If you call say:

```
select getvalue('a,b,c', ',', 1) as first,
  getvalue('a,b,c', ',', 2) as second,
  getvalue('a,b,c', ',', 3) as third
from dual;

FIRST  SECOND THIRD
------ ------ ------
a      b      (null)
```

... then you'll get null back instead of `c`. When you ask for the third element your `instr` is looking for the third comma, but the input string only has two commas - you'd usually expect to see one fewer separator than there are elements. `INSTR('a,b,c', ',', 1, 3` is zero. You're trying to deal with that later in the function when you calculate `j`, but you've already returned null from the previous check that `i = 0`. You can clean that up, but you could also use `regexp_substr` to replace the whole function:

```
V_USER_ID:= regexp_substr(I_USER_ID(i), '[^,]+', 1, 1);
```

Or more generically to find the "ith" element of a comma-separated string:

```
regexp_substr(<value>, '[^,]+', 1, i);
```

For example:

```
select regexp_substr('a,b,c', '[^,]+', 1, 1) as first,
  regexp_substr('a,b,c', '[^,]+', 1, 2) as second,
  regexp_substr('a,b,c', '[^,]+', 1, 3) as third
from dual;

FIRST  SECOND THIRD
------ ------ ------
a      b      c
```

Comment: That is what i needed. I wanted to fit in the first element from every pair and that din work with 'i' ,Thanks for your help. That worked when i replaced it with 1. thanks again!!!!